# In triangle ABC where BD is the height of a triangle: AE is the bisector of angle A: EF is perpendicular of AC, find EF if BD is 30 cm and AB/AC=7/8

Tags: geometry, triangles

We have triangle ABC where BD is the height of a triangle: AE is the bisector of angle A: EF is perpendicular of AC, find EF if BD is 30 cm and AB/AC=7/8
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1wFp.jpg)

Comment: Do you know the [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem), to get that $\dfrac{BE}{CE} = \dfrac78$?